# php, curl, curl_exec()

Tags: php, curl

i'm stuck to try handle a random name and value of form html to post data through curl.
here my code.

```
function grapvalue($html){

//parse content to grap name and value random

}

$opt = array(
         CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
         CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
         CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt'
         CURLOPT_POST => true,
         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => grapvalue($html)
       )

$init = curl_init("site.com")
curl_setopt_array($init,$opt)
$html = curl_exec($init)
```

I have to execute the function curl_exec () twice, first I have to execute the curl_exec function to retrieve the html to get the names and random values​​, then send the data.
how do I resolve this?

Comment: So you need to make a request to find out what the form fields are, then another to actually submit them? Why can't you hard-code the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full solution:

```
//First, we make a request to grab the variables
function grapvalue(){

$opt = array(
     CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
     CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt'
   );

$init = curl_init("site.com");
curl_setopt_array($init,$opt);
$html = curl_exec($init);

//parse content to grap name and value random

}

//Than, just call grapvalue() without any parameters
$opt = array(
     CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'cookie.txt',
     CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookie.txt'
     CURLOPT_POST => true,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => grapvalue()
   );

$init = curl_init("site.com");
curl_setopt_array($init,$opt);
$html = curl_exec($init);
```

*Tip: you may prefer using `CURLOPT_COOKIE` rather than `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`.*

Comment: @develroot, I still could not send the post data, I do not know what causes it?
can I ask for your email address? I'll send all the code that I created.

Comment: finally my script has been successfully running without an error! thanks a lot everyone. .

Comment: yes, definitely I received and it was very helpful. thanks dude.

Comment: so sorry mr.develroot i just realized what you mean when it,after I opened the link that you given above.thanks! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't create a `function cURL()`, call the function, get the `$html` and call again with the post values?

Comment: here the sample code i wanna get and post after parse to get value random with a single request.
  `<input type=hidden name=randomvalue value=randomvalue/>                
  <input type=text name=randomvalue />               
  <textarea name=randomvalue cols=3 /></textarea>`

everytime the name and value are random.
sorry, i can't speak english well dude

Comment: @mac786751 You can't do it with a single request. By the way, the cURL function can work for get/post requests:
http://pastebin.com/7Vnw1vjJ